# How do you access JSS Dictionary values programmatically in C#?

Tags: jss, dictionary

We have a [jss](/questions/tagged/jss) application that makes use of the JSS `Dictionary` to display values in the application. At the same time, we would like to re-use the same content labels in an email that is being sent via a GraphQL call to the C#.

So how do we access the JSS Dictionary via `C#` programmatically to achieve content re-use?

Answer (score 3):

## Background

The following assumes you have a Sitecore instance with JSS installed and a JSS application you are working on. Grab your favourite de-compilation tool (I use ILSpy) and locate the following DLL in the bin folder of your running Sitecore instance:

- `Sitecore.JavaScriptServices.Globalization.dll`

Once you have that open in ILSpy you want to have a search for DictionaryServiceController

```
public class DictionaryServiceController : ApiController
```

The following method is what we want to use in our C# code:

```
public DictionaryServiceResult GetDictionary(string appName, string language)
```

It takes the unique application name (that belongs to your application) and the language (“en”) as a parameter. As a result, you will get back a dictionary object that you can use to lookup up your content.

This is the `Controller` that would normally be called via an API on the front end. So how do we call it from normal C# service for instance?

Firstly, the controller has a constructor that has three parameters that are injected via DI (Dependency Injection).

```
IConfigurationResolver configurationResolver, 
BaseLanguageManager languageManager, 
IApplicationDictionaryReader appDictionaryReader
```

Using ILSpy once again you can find that the above three parameters are all set up in the DI container via `RegisterDependencies.cs` in various JSS assemblies. The Controller itself is already registered in the DI Container as well, which is very handy.

If you have a look at `showconfig.aspx` in the admin tools you can see that a lot of the dependencies are registered via RegisterDependencies.cs

for example:

```
<configurator type="Sitecore.JavaScriptServices.AppServices.RegisterDependencies, Sitecore.JavaScriptServices.AppServices" patch:source="Sitecore.JavaScriptServices.AppServices.config"/>
```

## Code Example

Using the above knowledge here is an example class that you can add to C# code that allows access to the JSS dictionary.

```
using Sitecore.Foundation.DependencyInjection; // Borrowed from habitat
using Sitecore.Diagnostics;
using Sitecore.JavaScriptServices.Globalization.Controllers;

namespace Sitecore.Foundation.JSS.Services
{
    public interface ITranslationService
    {
        string TranslateKey(string key);
    }

    [Service(typeof(ITranslationService), Lifetime = Lifetime.Transient)] 
    public class TranslationService : ITranslationService
    {
         private readonly DictionaryServiceController controller;

        public TranslationService(DictionaryServiceController controller)
        {
             this._controller = controller;
        }

        public string TranslateKey(string key)
        {
            var dictionary = GetDictionary();
            if (dictionary.phrases.ContainsKey(key))
                return dictionary.phrases[key];
            Log.Error("Dictionary key {key} not found", this);
            return string.Empty;
        }

        private DictionaryServiceResult GetDictionary(string appName = "myAppName", string language = "en")
        {
           return _controller.GetDictionary(appName, "en");
        }
    }
}
```

- Change the appName and language as required to access your JSS dictionary.
- Also, remember to publish your app dictionary to the web database or you may get no results.
- Call TranslateKey as needed with your desired key to get values back.
- The above code uses [Attribute Style DI as seen here.](https://github.com/Sitecore/Habitat/tree/master/src/Foundation/DependencyInjection/code). This will need adjusting as per your preferred method.